# Accessing Image Sub regions

Tags: computer-vision

how to extract 50x50  image sub-regions from the top-left and bottom-right sub-regions of the image and compute their SSD (Sum of Squared Differences).
The Size of the image is 256x256.

I am trying to do this using Matlab:

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
subimg1 = img(1:50,1:50);
subimg2 = img(  end -49 :end,  end -49 :end);
SSD = sum(sum((double(subimg1) - double(subimg2)).^2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple,everything is already given. just follow those remaining steps

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif') 
subimg1 = img(1:50,1:50) 
subimg2 = img( end -49 :end, end -49 :end) 
SSD = sum(sum((double(subimg1) - double(subimg2)).^2))
imshow(img) 
imshow(subimg1) 
imshow(subimg2) 
imshow(SSD)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Udit! Can you describe the remaining steps to give a more complete and detailed answer for the OP?